# Cannot call error Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am writing a function which is supposed to take a list s and a value v, and return an ordered list containing that value. Here is my code:

```
(define (add s v)
(cond ((empty? s) (list v))
  ((contains? s v) s)
      ((< v (car s)) (append (list v)  s))
      ((> v (car s)) (append (list (car s)) ((add (cdr s) v)))) 
      )
)
```

I keep getting an error "cannot call (some list)." I'm brand new to scheme and I am wondering what this error means?

Comment: In Scheme `add` is a variable and if you surround it with parentheses it's a procedure call `(add (cdr s) v)`. `((add (cdr s) v))` has two. One for to get the result (a list) and a second to try to call the list as if it was a procedure. It will fail but Scheme only finds out in runtime. Strip off the extra set and it will work. Also know that you are checking `contains?` for each step in the process of putting the value in the right spot.

Comment: Oh. Thank you for the explanation and the help!